# How can I get my image's output cleaner?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, png, photoshop-effects

I used a web safe red and I'm still getting a somewhat distorted output. I'm saving in .png format. I've noticed this happening a lot whenever a red color is used. The output looks HORRIBLE on Faceboook and Instagram. I have it at 300 dpi for printing. I'd like the image that appears on the internet to be just as clear as when I print it. I did a screenshot of it on Facebook and included it with this question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer is in that previous Q&A. Basically Facebook compresses images. They say to keep images under 100kb for the best results but theres no way to stop them processing your images completely

Comment: Does this also apply to Instagram where we do a LOT of promoting?

Comment: The compression, yes. I'm not sure how file size affects that though. ([previous Q&A regarding Instagram](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/76401/52050))

Comment: From the looks of it, the problem is in the black. I can't see how compression would affect the black as shown. Please have a look at how the black is handled overprinting the red. Something looks as if it has been done twice.

Comment: Nothing was done to the black portions. You're seeing the actual texture from the original photos. The only thing I did was turn up the resolution and did a red photo filter on the images.